# Visual Studio Code, HTML tag not paired and highlighted in PHP files

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

is there a way to "pair" and "highlight" the HTML tags in PHP files as normally done in HTML files? (please refer to the attached image for visual explanation).
Thanks[mixed-html-php-content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3Q5X.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you want you can change the language of your file with the option found below right:

[image]

click on label **PHP** and select **HTML** and ready!

I hope this will be helpful

Regards

Comment: thanks, I know the trick. I was just wondering if there was a setting in Visual Studio Code to have an automatic recognition of HTML tags in mixed HTML / PHP content (like other editors do) without the need to switch forth and back between languages.

Comment: Can confirm setting this to PHP works. It seems like the PHP setting will syntax highlight for HTML and PHP content (the part I doubted, but works) where as the HTML setting only syntax highlights HTML and not PHP (as expected).

Answer (score 0):

You can have extension HTTP snipets which will do you the right thing
Installation and settings:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45279141/8187926