# Visual Studio Code not matching html tags

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code for writing html but it doesn't have the feature of identifying closing tag for the current selected one.
How can I achieve the same?

Here is how it looks on VS Code:

[image]

Can you suggest any extension or how can I achieve this?
VS Code 1.7.1

Answer (score 38):

install this extension

[highlight-matching-tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag)

and change the `settings.json` to

```
"highlight-matching-tag.leftStyle": {
    "borderWidth": "0 0 0 3px",
    "borderStyle": "dotted",
    "borderColor": "red",
    "borderRadius": "5px"
 },
```

Comment: Where to find settings.json file?

Comment: ctrl-p then ">settings" then once you're on that screen, find "extensions > highlight matching tag" then click any of the underlined "settings.json" links

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you very much a hundred times.

Answer (score 10):

I think you chose PHP or something else for "language mode", change it on HTML

Comment: This is a fix which will break other things, then php specific syntax highlighting will not work.

Comment: It seems that it's unavailable in vscode other modes than html, I needed tag matching in JSX so I wrote a small extension for that: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag

Comment: @Aleksey Dubinskiy   Where should I change it ?

Comment: Right-bottom corner or View > Command Palette... > Change Language Mode

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if you have any extensions installed that break the highlighting? If I use your example, it highlights the closing tag fine by default:

[image]

Additionally, there is a builtin Emmet command that jumps between the beginning/closing tag. In the command palette, you can search for 'Emmet: Go to Matching Pair".

If you bind it to a shortcut, you can press that for example twice to see the cursor jumping between your tag. The name of the command to bind is `editor.emmet.action.matchingPair`

Comment: I don't think that any extension is causing this as I have all extensions disabled.
@kwood Also can you confirm if your vs code version is 1.7.1

Comment: @AnkitSinghaniya It's 1.7.1 and I checked with --disable-extensions

Comment: I got got a reply on my issue from vs code.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15285#issuecomment-259652115
It will work with `.html` extension only.

Comment: You can associate the file to the desired type.  Bottom-right of the window is where I go to do that.  In a PHP file, you can associate it to HTML to get this behaviour, and then switch back.  Pretty slick, really.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue and HTML snippet extension solve it. Just install it [Html snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UPjQ.png)

and just do some changes in setting, goto file->preferences->setting,
you can now see User settings in the right hand side, add the following code

```
,"files.associations": {
    // extension name : html
    "*.php": "html",
    "*.html": "html"
}
```

and you are ready to go. Enjoy :)

Comment: Sorry had to down vote, this answer removes syntax highlighting from actual PHP syntax, meaning things like controllers you may as well open in Notepad.

Answer (score 4):

The best visual way that i found to do this is with a plugin [highlight-matching-tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag)

```
"highlight-matching-tag.styles": {
     "opening": {
         "full": {
             "highlight": "rgba(165, 153, 233, 0.3)"
         }
     }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

VSCode now supports matching tag highlighting by default:

[image: Matching tag highlighting]

Answer (score 2):

Install "Bracket Pair Colorizer" extension.
File -> Preference -> Settings -> User Settings(Text Editor). You can edit in json view.

[image: File->Preference->Settings->User Settings(Text Editor)]

Answer (score 2):

first confirm your visual studio have this extension it install default but for safe side you can check and solve highlight problem with matched div with this steps:

1. Go to the visual studio and type `Ctrl+P`
2. Make sure
3. Open `preferences` > `setting`
4. Paste this:

---

```
"editor.occurrencesHighlight": false,
"highlight-matching-tag.styles": {
  "opening": {
    "name": {
      "underline": "red"
    }
  }
}
```

---

first line for disabled highlights.

you can choose color : red or anything else
may be it's help to you

@thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue too. If you click and drag it selects all words with that text highlighted, but if you just single click it seems to select the closing tag. So yeah just single click a tag to get the pair, don't double click or click and drag.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue with Some Tags matching and highlighting while others don't.

The Weird thing was if I created a new file, and put a bunch of tags in they all highlighted correctly.

Turns out that that the person that created the original page used `</br>` for line breaks.  This broke the highlighting of open and closing tags where a `</br>` happened between them.   I changed the `</br>` to `<br />` and everything is happy now.

It also happened with `<link></link>`, that I fixed by removing the closing tag.

I would suggest that if you are having this issue to look for closing tags that are not needed/ required.